# Erro com MySQL - requisição expirou

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, conexão, password

Estou utilizando o MySQL, porém estou tendo que redefinir a senha toda vez que reinicio o meu notebook . Utilizo o Sequel pro para acessar o banco e dar o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível conectar no host 127.0.0.1, ou a requisição expirou.
>
> Certifique-se de que o endereço está correto e que você tem os
>   privilégios necessários, ou tente aumentar o tempo limite de conexão
>   (atualmente 10 segundos).

Comment: Lucas não entendi muito bem, toda vez voce tem de 'Redefinir' sua senha ou somente efetuar novamente o login?

Comment: Acontecia isso quando tentava efetuar novamente o login, conseguir concerta utilizando uma nova versão do MySQL e  trocando de Use Strong Password Encryption para Use Legacy Password Encryption e redefinindo uma nova senha !